# VLC changes the resolution from 1360x768 to 1365x786(ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: video, resolution, vlc-media-player, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using VLC player(ver 2.2.2) to render video data from FPGA device. I have provided resolution in vlc width: 1360 and height: 768 from Advance option in VLC (media==>Open Capture Device ==> Catpure Device ==> Capture mode ==> Video Camera ==> Device Selection /dev/video0 (video0 is FPGA device). Click on Advance Options... Video input chroma format is "RV24" width "1360" and height "768"). VLC when it renders, video output is amiss. To confirm whether resolution is correct or not, goto (Tools==>Codec Information ==>Codec) it shows as Resolution : 1365x768 and Display Resolution: 1360x768. Because of Resolution is 1365x768 video output in vlc goes bad.

I have enabled the verbosity in VLC (2(debug)) from this it shows as "added new video ES RV24 1360x768 (1365x768) when resolution was 1360x768.

However, If use OBS player then it render proper video for same resolution (1360x768) and RGB24. I have observed the log in OBS, it never changes like VLC, it remains same as 1360x768.

Queries: 1) Why VLC changes the resolution from 1360x768 to 1365x768 ?

2) Which is correct resolution, is it 1360x768 or 1365x768 ?

3) What is difference in Resolution and Display Resolution in VLC ?

4) How OBS render properly, why not VLC ?